# Error reporting behavior in CLI binary

Tags: php, command-line-interface

`test.php` contains the following line:

```
<?php echo 1 / 0; ?>
```

PHP version is `5.4.0 (cli)`

Now, a series of tests with `display_errors`:

- `display_errors = Off` [image: image1]
- `display_errors = stderr` [image: image2]
- `display_errors = stdout` [image: image3]

Why does `Off` not turn off error display on `stdout`?

Why do both `stdout` and `stderr` end up printing to both outputs simultaneously?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Why does Off not turn off error display on stdout?

I suppose because error_log is not set. If it is set, errors are not displayed. If it not set, PHP will use the SAPI error logger, which is stderr (= stdout) in CLI. See:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
echo 1 / 0; // Prints a warning.

ini_set('error_log', '/dev/null');
echo 1 / 0; // No warning on the standard output.
```

> Why do both stdout and stderr end up printing to both outputs simultaneously?

The first error was sent to the SAPI error logger, the second was sent to stdout (display_errors = on). Both messages are displayed because as I mentioned above, the SAPI error logger is stderr, which is also stdout in this case.

Comment: Note: The Windows equivalent of `/dev/null` is `nul`